# Merge multidimensional array having the same keyname

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and I would like display the values in a table.

Here is the code:

```
$attributes = [
    [
        "attributeName"=> "Name",
        "value"=> "Paul"
    ],
    [
        "attributeName"=> "Name",
        "value"=> "Steve"
    ],
    [
        "attributeName"=> "Name",
        "value"=> "John"
    ],
    [
        "attributeName"=> "Name",
        "value"=> "Andrew"
    ],

    [
        "attributeName"=> "Destination",
        "value"=> "London"
    ],
    [
        "attributeName"=> "Destination",
        "value"=> "Paris"
    ],
    [
        "attributeName"=> "Destination",
        "value"=> "Ankara"
    ],
    [
        "attributeName"=> "Destination",
        "value"=> "Kuwait"
    ],
];
```

I would like the output to be on a table with the thead being Name And Destination and the while the td being the values of Name and Destinations.

Or this

**Name**: Paul,Steve,John,Andrew

**Destination**: London,Paris,Ankara,Kuwait

Comment: @Nick, why do you have to redirect me to a question that is totally confusing which is completely different. I have gone through the link and I do not understand any thing there. Please I need to see the answer someone drop on my question

Comment: You can as well answer my question or show my the answer someone drop. This is really frustrating.

Comment: Actually it was my answer and I deleted it because I felt the question is a duplicate. I've undeleted the answer, take a look and see what you think.

Comment: Note also that I changed the duplicate target - I think it is a much better one than the question was originally closed with. Again, please take a look at that and let me know what you think?

Comment: Thank you Nick. I really appreciate. Actually what I want is for it to be printed in table format but since I am having difficult showing the table on Stackflow editor I decided go the simple form. Thank you once again for reopening it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to group all the attributes into an output array:

```
$output = array_reduce($attributes, function ($carry, $arr) {
    $carry[$arr['attributeName']][] = $arr['value'];
    return $carry;
}, array());
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paul
            [1] => Steve
            [2] => John
            [3] => Andrew
        )
    [Destination] => Array
        (
            [0] => London
            [1] => Paris
            [2] => Ankara
            [3] => Kuwait
        )
)
```

To output that as a table, you can use a `foreach` loop:

```
echo "<table>\n";
foreach ($output as $key => $values) {
    echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>" . implode('</td><td>', $values) . "</td></tr>\n";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Output:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Paul</td><td>Steve</td><td>John</td><td>Andrew</td></tr>
<tr><td>Destination</td><td>London</td><td>Paris</td><td>Ankara</td><td>Kuwait</td></tr>
</table>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/O8HHk)

Comment: @Prince actually the table isn't in the right orientation I don't think, the data is horizontal instead of vertical

Comment: Yes. I just modified it on my code. But your answer is the solution to my question. I just modified your table output to get the perfect table I am looking for. Thanks